# Rx Java, what's the difference between subscribe({}) vs subscribe { }?

Tags: kotlin, rx-java

```
Observable.just(10,20,30,40,50)
            .subscribe { Consumer<Int>{
                Log.d(TAG, "Where I'm I" + Thread.currentThread())
                System.out.println("Hello boss")
                Toast.makeText(baseContext.applicationContext, "Hellloo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } }
```

**vs**

```
 Observable.just(10,20,30,40,50)
            .subscribe( { Consumer<Int>{
                Log.d(TAG, "Where I'm I" + Thread.currentThread())
                System.out.println("Hello boss")
                Toast.makeText(baseContext.applicationContext, "Hellloo",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            } })
```

What's the difference between calling `subscribe({}) vs subscribe { }`

Comment: Where are you getting the examples from?

Comment: Please don't post quizes. Instead, describe what difference you observe and then ask why that is a difference.

Comment: No difference, just Kotlin trailing lambdas and not.

Answer (score 2):

With respect to `RxJava` there is no difference. Calling and execution stays the same. Its just a special syntax in `kotlin` known as `trailing lambda`.

In kotlin if you have a `function` with a `lambda` as last parameter then you can move that `lambda` out of parentheses. If the `lambda` is the only parameter then you can also remove the parentheses.

From the [kotlin docs](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/lambdas.html#passing-a-lambda-to-the-last-parameter)

> Passing trailing lambdas
>
> In Kotlin, there is a convention: if the last parameter of a function
>   is a function, then a lambda expression passed as the corresponding
>   argument can be placed outside the parentheses:
>
> ```
> // Second argument of fold is of function type,
> // hence we have moved the lambda out of parentheses.
> val product = items.fold(1) { acc, e -> acc * e }
> ```
>
> Such syntax is also known as trailing lambda.
>
> If the lambda is the only argument to that call, the parentheses can
>   be omitted entirely:
>
> ```
> // run only takes a single argument of function type,
> // hence we have omitted the parentheses.
> run { println("...") }
> ```